# How to navigate to a specific Activity in Android (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I've added six buttons on my layout XML file, but when I run the app, I have to tap all of the previous buttons to access the activity I desire to open.

My question is:

How can I modify my code to set the buttons to access straightforward the activity  I want to?

I'm using Android Studio 2020 v4.0.1
Kotlin 1.4

Here's my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/morgan_02"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/dark_02_02">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nexarustsans_black"
                android:text="My Dashboard"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="26sp" />

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_margin="30dp"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:rowCount="4">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="130dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="#002D2D2D"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:cardElevation="5dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/asset_32" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="130dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="#002D2D2D"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:cardElevation="5dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/asset_31" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="130dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="#002D2D2D"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:cardElevation="5dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/asset_5" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="130dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="#002D2D2D"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:cardElevation="5dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/asset_3" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="130dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="#002D2D2D"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:cardElevation="5dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button5"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/asset_6" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="130dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="#002D2D2D"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:cardElevation="5dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button6"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/asset_2" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        </GridLayout>
      </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's my MainActivity.kt

```
package www.sanju.my dashboard

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import www.sanju.mydashboard.R.layout.activity_main

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(activity_main)

        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN

        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity2::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)

        val button2 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2)
        button2.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, Myprojects::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)

        val button3 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button3)
        button3.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, Competitors::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)

        val button4 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button4)
        button4.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, Market::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)

        val button5 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button5)
        button5.setOnClickListener {
           val intent = Intent(this, Compareit::class.java)
           startActivity(intent)

        val button6 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button6)
        button6.setOnClickListener {
           val intent = Intent(this, Prices::class.java)
           startActivity(intent)
    }

}}}}}}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are nesting this `onClickListeners`. Your code is formatted wrongly. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to reformat Your code and You see that Your `onClickListeners` are nasted. Do it like this and it should works:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(activity_main)

        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN

        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity2::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        
        val button2 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2)
        button2.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, Myprojects::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        val button3 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button3)
        button3.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, Competitors::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        val button4 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button4)
        button4.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, Market::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        val button5 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button5)
        button5.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, Compareit::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        val button6 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button6)
        button6.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, Prices::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

---

*Look also at [cactustictacs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13598222/cactustictacs) answer also. There is a good explanation of how to avoid so much boilerplate code and make it prettier. My answer just showed why Your code isn't working but it still can be improved :D*

Comment: Hey thanks! And this is the better answer anyway (answering the OP's question instead of oh hay how about you rewrite everything), I just wanted to nudge them towards making their life easier

Answer (score 2):

Just to build off iknow's answer because I like to encourage good habits! Get all that repeated code in a nice function, and make it handle each button appropriately

```
fun handleButtonClick(button: View) {
    val activityType = when(button.id) {
        R.id.button -> MainActivity2::class.java
        R.id.button2 -> Myprojects::class.java
        // etc
        else -> return
    }
    val intent = Intent(this, activityType)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Then you can set the click listeners with one line

```
button.setOnClickListener { handleButtonClick(it) }
```

or, since `View.onClickListener` has a single function that takes a single `View` parameter, and that's exactly what `handleButtonClick` is too, we can pass a function reference to that instead

```
button.setOnClickListener(::handleButtonClick)
```

you could do them all in one go (since they're all using the same function)

```
listOf(button, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6)
    .forEach { setOnClickListener(::handleButtonClick) }
```

or, if you're not actually storing those button references (and you're just assigning them to local `val`s so you can refer to them on the next line, where you assign the click listener) you could do the lookups too

```
listOf(R.id.button, R.id.button2, R.id.button3, R.id.button4, R.id.button5, R.id.button6)
    .map { findViewById<Button>(it) }
    .forEach { setOnClickListener(::handleButtonClick) }
```

I know this might be going a little too far for some people, but I just want to encourage people to think about how they can trim stuff down into neater code. Because when you're managing a whole bunch of things with repeated code everywhere it can get harder to handle and reason about

Comment: Great explanation!

Comment: Wow, great answer!

Thank you for taking the time to dive deeper. Unfortunately for me, you're right. I'm a rookie at developing. Therefore, I'll need some time to digest your suggestions. I knew I had to resume my code by listing the buttons, but I didn't know how to do it. I'm learning with practice.

Comment: It's cool, no rush! There are a few concepts going on in there - Kotlin makes it easy to be nice and concise, but you need to be familiar with those tools, so don't worry about understanding everything. Really I just wanted to show what you can aim for and how it can help you wrangle things - the main takeaway is having that reusable click listener so you don't need to repeat yourself. If you ever find yourself doing basically the same thing several times, make it a function!